# struct return error-C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, matrix, return-value

this program is written in C

it supposed to get a two D array( matrixAdd) and scan it with scanMtx (the scanning function isn't here becuase the code isn't relevant)

the problem: the EDMtx function return the scanning matrix 1,1,1,,1,-8,1,,1,1,1
when it return back to main it is : 0,0,0,0,0,0,junk,junk,junk

it seems that there is a address error

what did i do wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct matrix
{
    int* ptr;
    int row;
    int column;
};

matrix EDMtx();

void main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int matrixAdd[5][5]={{1,1,1,3,4},{1,1,1,3,4},{1,1,1,3,4},{1,1,1,3,4},{1,1,1,3,4}};
    matrix mtx;
    matrix scanMtx;

    mtx.ptr=&matrixAdd[0][0];
    mtx.row=5;
    mtx.column=5;

    scanMtx= EDMtx();

//  mtx= ScanM(mtx,1,1,scanMtx);- doesn't important to you.

    getchar();
}
matrix EDMtx()

{

    int matrx[3][3]={{1,1,1},{1,-8,1},{1,1,1}};
    matrix Mtx;

    Mtx.ptr=&matrx[0][0];
    Mtx.row=3;
    Mtx.column=3;

    return Mtx;
}
```

Comment: Just a question: are you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: no compiler warning or errors at all (using microsoft visual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `matrixAdd` and `matrx`, and the memory they point to, have local scope only. If you want them to persist after returning from a function, either declare them `static`, or redesign your code logic. (e.g. by using `malloc` to allocate memory explicitly)

Comment: @almog No doubt mvds is good, but taking the address of a local is always a red flag. `matrixAdd` can't escape `main` (nothing can) so there's no problem with using its address. But `&matrix` escapes `EDMtx` ... that's the bug.

Comment: @almog It's not enough at SO to say people are good -- put your words into action by accepting a good answer.

Comment: @Jim: True, I didn't emphasize that but you probably *should* redesign the logic. E.g. by putting the matrix data inside the struct.

Answer (score 0):

In EDMtx, Mtx.ptr is pointed to a stack variable. This is getting destroyed probably. If you want to exchange pointers to variables they must be on the heap

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix EDMtx()
{

    int matrx[3][3]={{1,1,1},{1,-8,1},{1,1,1}};

    matrix Mtx;
    Mtx.ptr=&matrx[0][0];
    Mtx.row=3;
    Mtx.column=3;

    return Mtx;

}
```

`matrx` is a local variable. So, it goes out of scope when upon return of `EDMtx()`. And the `Mtx.ptr` has the reference of the local variable `matrx`. And so the pointer member of `scnMtx`, is getting garbage values upon dereferencing. **Never return references of a local variable.**